# How to rename your app in itunesconnect?

Tags: iphone, itunes, rename, app-store-connect

Is there any way to rename you app in itunes connect?

Answer (score 36):

Yes, but only at the time when you submit a new version or if the app hasn't gone live yet.

Comment: Not true.  Just edit "version information".  No submission is required.

Comment: @wallacer: Then you seem to have access to a different version of iTunes Connect. Just verified: The app name is not modifiable without a new submission, at least not if the app is approved and for sale, currently.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been along time since you asked this question. But if I just press submit 5 minutes ago and my app is "Waiting For Review" then I rename my app, does it update with the current build or it will change when I submit the new build? "Remove from Review" is not display on my app at this time.

Answer (score 7):

Now you can rename your app's name while uploading new version. You can edit your app name inside metadata information.

Answer (score 4):

Open iTunes connect page with your application.

Then open version of application and press "Edit" near "Metadata and Uploads".
You can edit there.

You can change the app name if application is not yet released in AppStore, phase 'Waiting For Review' is ok

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to submit a new version (If you haven't gone live yet), Nor is it impossible.

Click on the app to go to App details.  At the top beside "Version Information" click edit.  Change the app name and press save.

That's it!  :D

Comment: Update: For apps that have not gone live, the name is in "Manage Your Apps" > (your app) > "Current Version" > "View Details" > "App Localizations" > "App Name".

Answer (score 1):

Home -> Manage Your Applications -> yourapp -> Versions (if you already have multiple versions, otherwise it will just be Version Information)

The app name is listed under Version Information but there's no way I can see to edit the Version Information of a submitted and approved app.
You can only edit the app metadata and that does not include the name.

You need to create a new version and you will be able to put in a new app name.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your application is in Waiting for review mode then you can change your app name inside Viewdetails->Metadata and Uploads->app name
2. If your application is in live mode then you need to submit new version with new name.

Answer (score -1):

You can rename the name of the app on the Applications Manager inside iTunes Connect. Choose the app. Edit it. That is simple.

To alter the name that shows under the icon you need to change the .plist config file inside the app package and upload it again. The standard is the Project name itself but you can change this in the bundle.

Comment: Hi Rui, thanks for your reply. I can change the app description only. Can you explan the process in detail?

Comment: it's impossible rename app name inside iTunes Connect.