# Updating app on app store and renaming the app name

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an approved app on app store and I want to upload a new version. I also want to rename my app. I have searched on Google and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371736/renaming-an-approved-iphone-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413085/how-to-rename-your-app-in-itunesconnect) solution but I am getting signing issues while uploading new build on app store using XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You should have same **Bundle Identifier** in itunesconnect and your project file.

Check your distribution certificate also.

If three are matching then there will not be any issue.