# App Store application renaming

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rename your app in itunesconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413085/how-to-rename-your-app-in-itunesconnect)

Two months ago I published an iPhone application called "iSMaC." Now I need to change the name to "mySMaC." I made a version 1.1 with the new name in iTunes Connect and I modified "Bundle display name" from Xcode.
With Organizer I uploaded the application correctly.

Now I would like to know ... when the application is approved by Apple, which will be the name in the App Store? "mySMaC" (new name) or "iSMaC" (old name)?
Thank you!

Comment: you may want to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413085/how-to-rename-your-app-in-itunesconnect

Comment: It is not a duplicate... I did not ask "how to"!
I know how to do it!

Comment: Thanks Ares but I have not found the answer to my question.

Comment: I finally published the application with the new name.
I can say that the name in the app store becomes the newest one.