# Rename a app in itunesconnect - migrate data?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am about to submit a new app through itunesconnect. I read a couple of renaming questions ([How to rename your app in itunesconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413085/how-to-rename-your-app-in-itunesconnect)), but I have a more detailed question: would the user generated data migrate into the renamed version when I renamed it or would it start off from scratch again (this is exactly what I worry about - user data would be gone).

Answer (score 1):

The user data is stored in the app container. The container ID is determined by the bundle ID. You're fine.

Comment: I don't think he's fine by that logic. If he's submitting a new app in iTunes connect, it cannot have the same bundle ID as the original one.

Comment: Jacob, you are correct of course. But I read the original problem description as "submit a new *version* of the app" considering the title "Rename a app in itunesconnect". Maybe the author can clarify.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, I just read submit a new app, so that's why I figured it was a new app in itunes connect...

Comment: So, what's the consensus. You think it woun't work? I edited the question.

Comment: It will work if you keep the bundle id. That is, in iTunes Connect you go to your app's details and add a version. And that new version will receive your new name. As opposed to deleting the old app and creating a new one.